# SIFT keypoints in sift.detect

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, feature-detection, sift, keypoint

How are keypoints stored using the sift.detect method in opencv ? Are they in the form of an array ? How to extract the (x,y) coordinates of each keypoint? ( I am using opencv 2.4.11)

Comment: Is the [internet](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) broken?

Comment: After performing detection of SIFT using `kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
`, try printing the variable `kp` and see for yourself. See what data type `kp` is and understand how to extract what it contains using `numpy`. Hope your internet is not broken as @EdChum asks. ..... LOL!